# Unable to send data to server in Json format using Soap Api getting base64 image can not be serlize

Tags: android, soap

```
class download1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SoapObject objSaveVisitInfraDetails = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                    PostMETHOD_NAME);
            JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject pnObj = new JSONObject();
            TreeMap<Integer, String> map=new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                pnObj.put("Feedback",
                        "This is feedBack");
                pnObj.put("InfraVisit", Integer.parseInt("1"));
                map.put(i+1,org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(byteArray));
                pnObj.put("InfraId", Integer.parseInt("1"));
                pnObj.put("ResolveStatus", Boolean.valueOf("true"));
                pnObj.put("VisitDetailId",  Integer.parseInt("1"));
                pnObj.put("Visit_MasterId",  Integer.parseInt("1"));
                jsonArr.put(pnObj);

            }

            objSaveVisitInfraDetails.addProperty("jsonString",
                    jsonArr.toString());
            objSaveVisitInfraDetails.addProperty("VisitMasterId", 1);
            objSaveVisitInfraDetails.addProperty("dicImage", map);

            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(objSaveVisitInfraDetails);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            Marshal dateMarshal = new MarshalBase64();
            dateMarshal.register(envelope);
            androidHttpTransport.call(PostSOAP_ACTION, envelope);   
            Log.d("RESPONSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE",
                    androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d("RESPONSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE222",
                    androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            String Name = result.getProperty(0).toString();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Errorrr", e.getMessage());

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucess!  ", 10000).show();

    }

}
```

Hi this is my Asynktask for send multiple data to server using  one at a time i have convert all String data Json format and image in HashMap  base64 String format in key value pair but i am unable to send getting Error that Base64 String can not  be serialized please tell me how to send image so that we can serlized image and send data to server

Answer (score 0):

I have done this thing by using this code :

```
final byte temp[] = read(fileSelected);
            // Send Media
            ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if(isInternetPresent)
            {
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ibtnSendChatNote.setEnabled(false);
                final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xxxxx/xxxxxx/insertMedia";
                final String METHOD_NAME = "insertMedia";
                final String NAMESPACE = "http://xxxxx/";
                Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  try {
                        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
                        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(IPCONFIG.URL);
                        request.addProperty("sId", sId);
                        request.addProperty("noteContent", filePath[filePath.length-1]);
                        request.addProperty("noteType", "Mobile");
                        request.addProperty("mediaContent", temp);                          
                        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        final SoapPrimitive sp = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                        runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);                
                                ibtnSendChatNote.setEnabled(true);
                                if(sp.toString().equals("true"))
                                {
                                    // Do what ever you want to do
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                ibtnSendChatNote.setEnabled(true);
                             }
                         });
                  }
                  catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
                };
                networkThread.start();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Connect to Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Get the byte[] using filePath

```
public static byte[] read(String filePath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fis.read(b);
            fis.close();
            return b;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Refer my code as a reference for transfer byte[] in Ksoap2

Comment: map.put(i+1,org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(byteArray));  this i have use to convert byte array into base64 cant be send like this i am sending image @sanat shukla  there is minor mistake please check it

Comment: try passing direct byte[] in your map without base64 conversion like map.put(i+1,byteArray);

Comment: here data  base64 can not be serilize here this telling how to fix it